# PIVOT help on SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Input follows :

```
MID   NAME   ACTIVESTATUS    DID    DNAME   STATUS
1A    SRN      ACTIVE         1     FEEVER    NEW
1A    SRN       ACTIVE        2     MOTIONS   ACTIVE
1A    SRN      ACTIVE         3     SUGAR     INVALIDCODE
1A    SRN      ACTIVE         4     BP        ACTIVE-PRIMARY
```

Expected Output would be like :

```
MID   NAME   ACTIVESTATUS    FEVERSTATUS   MOTIONSTAUS   SUGATSTATUS   BPSTATUS
1      SRN     ACTIVE          NEW          ACTIVE       INVALIDCODE    ACTIVE-PRIMARY
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, will a particular value of `MID` have exactly 4 different values of `DNAME` tagged to it, like you have shown here?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

**Test Data**

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (MID VARCHAR(2),NAME VARCHAR(3),ACTIVESTATUS VARCHAR(10),DID TINYINT,DNAME VARCHAR(7),STATUS VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO @Table(MID,NAME,ACTIVESTATUS,DID,DNAME,STATUS) VALUES

('1A','SRN','ACTIVE','1','FEEVER','NEW'),
('1A','SRN','ACTIVE','2','MOTIONS','ACTIVE'),
('1A','SRN','ACTIVE','3','SUGAR','INVALIDCODE'),
('1A','SRN','ACTIVE','4','BP','ACTIVE-PRIMARY')
```

**Using Pivot**

```
SELECT   MID,
         NAME,
         ACTIVESTATUS,
         [FEEVER] AS FEVERSTATUS,
         [MOTIONS] AS MOTIONSTAUS,
         [SUGAR] AS SUGATSTATUS,
         [BP] AS BPSTATUS
FROM     (
             SELECT  LEFT(MID,1) AS MID,
                     NAME,
                     ACTIVESTATUS,
                     DNAME,
                     STATUS
             FROM    @Table t
         ) a
         PIVOT(
             MIN(STATUS)FOR DNAME in ([FEEVER],[MOTIONS],[SUGAR],[BP])
         )piv
```

**Without using Pivot**

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
         (
             SELECT  TOP 1 LEFT(MID, 1)
             FROM    @Table t
             WHERE tt.MID=t.MID
         )  AS MID,
         (
             SELECT  TOP 1      NAME
             FROM    @Table     t
             WHERE tt.MID=t.MID
         )  AS NAME,
         (
             SELECT  TOP 1      ACTIVESTATUS
             FROM    @Table     t
             WHERE tt.MID=t.MID
         )  AS ACTIVESTATUS,
                 (
             SELECT  TOP 1      STATUS
             FROM    @Table     t
             WHERE tt.MID=t.MID
             AND t.DID =1
         )  AS FEVERSTATUS,
                 (
             SELECT  TOP 1      STATUS
             FROM    @Table     t
             WHERE tt.MID=t.MID
             AND t.DID =2
         )  AS MOTIONSTAUS,
                 (
             SELECT  TOP 1      STATUS
             FROM    @Table     t
             WHERE tt.MID=t.MID
             AND t.DID =3
         )  AS SUGATSTATUS,
                 (
             SELECT  TOP 1      STATUS
             FROM    @Table     t
             WHERE tt.MID=t.MID
             AND t.DID =4
         )  AS BPSTATUS

FROM     @Table tt
```

Comment: You are hard-coding the status values in PIVOT as column name? Can you explain why you are doing that?

Comment: @shree.pat18 there are only 4 status right? you can do that by modifying the query to MIN(STATUS)FOR DNAME in ([FEEVER],[MOTIONS],[SUGAR],[BP])

Comment: I see you have updated your query now to pivot on the `dname` values, which is what I was getting at it.

Comment: @shree.pat18, right there are only two options to logically pivot and they are DNAME and STATUS. Anyways nice catch. Thanks.

Comment: You are right to say that there are only 2 options to pivot. However, it would make sense to pivot on `DNAME` only among the two, because, from the sample data given, the output is a kind of report of status for each of the 4 metrics, and not the other-way round.

Comment: yes, what you are saying makes more sense, for a broader scale,  segmenting by DNAME would be more ideal.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually very simple:

```
  SELECT mid,
         name,
         activestatus,
         MAX (CASE dname WHEN 'FEEVER' THEN status ELSE NULL END) AS feverstatus,
         MAX (CASE dname WHEN 'MOTIONS' THEN status ELSE NULL END)
             AS motionstatus,
         MAX (CASE dname WHEN 'INVALIDCODE' THEN status ELSE NULL END)
             AS sugarstatus,
         MAX (CASE dname WHEN 'BP' THEN status ELSE NULL END) AS bpstatus
    FROM myTable
GROUP BY mid, name, activestatus;
```

You will get your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT   mid,
         NAME,
         activestatus,
         feever   AS feverstatus,
         motions  AS motionstatus,
         sugar    AS sugarstatus,
         bp       AS bpstatus
FROM     (
             SELECT  mid,
                     NAME,
                     activestatus,
                     dname,
                     [status]
             FROM    tbl
         ) s
         PIVOT(
             MAX([status])
             FOR dname IN ([FEEVER], [MOTIONS], [SUGAR], [BP])
         )           p
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/ZBPLNR66011)

Note that this solution assumes that the only possible values for `dname` are the ones included in the `PIVOT` clause. If the values are not going to be the above 4 for every `mid`, then you will need to generate that list first using dynamic SQL and then do a pivot operation.